# Latest Ionic update changed local notifications native plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

After updating my node-modules to latest version, including ionic core etc. I got this error and I can’t seem to find anything about it? Some help please? Has anything changed to local notifications plugin or anything else that could get me this error?

```
[15:34:51] transpile started …
[15:35:10] typescript: D:/ionic/myApp1/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 13
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

L12: this.platform.ready().then(() => {
L13: this.localNoti.on(‘click’, (noti, state) => {

L14: alert(state);

Error: Failed to transpile program
at new BuildError (D:\ionic\myApp1\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util
\errors.js:16:28)
at D:\ionic\myApp1\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:159:20
at new Promise ()
at transpileWorker (D:\ionic\myApp1\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\tra
nspile.js:107:12)
at Object.transpile (D:\ionic\myApp1\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\tr
anspile.js:64:12)
at D:\ionic\myApp1\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:82
```

Answer (score 6):

Got this answer on Ionic forum by Hesters:

> Yeah I experienced the same. As always the Ionic Docs are shitty and
>   outdated.
>
> The .on() function now returns an observable. So what you want to do
>   is replace your code with this:
>
> ```
>   this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe(notification => {
>     // Insert your logic here
>   });
> ```
>
> This worked like a charm to fix this error.

Source link [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/latest-update-changed-local-notifications-plugin/127674/2)

Comment: If you are quoting something, you need to add the link to the source along with the original answerer if possible.

Comment: Sorry, pretty new to this. Will do in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the shoutout 